# ArrayBuffer to PDF in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

how to Convert Array Buffer Response into PDF using Angular 7
 here is my code

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('clientApp', 'BUI');
body.append('projectName', this.ProjectName);
body.append('repoPath', this.RepoPath);
this.http.post(environment.GetPreview + this.SiteID + '&tango_ticket=' + this.TangoToken, body, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' } ).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

response i am getting

[image]

Comment: You can use jsPDF to generate pdf from HTML or you need to use a server to generate a PDF for you.

Answer (score 0):

step-1
npm install file-saver --save
step-2

```
this.http.post(environment.GetPreview + this.SiteID + '&tango_ticket=' + this.TangoToken, body, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' } ).subscribe(res => {
   saveAs(res, 'response.pdf');
});
```